# C# WPF Как изменить Width или Height окна когда WindowState.Maximized?

Tags: c#, wpf

Собственно как изменить Width или Height окна когда WindowState.Maximized? У меня ничего не происходит. ActualWidth и ActualHeight - readonly

Comment: А как вы себе это представляете?

Comment: Сменить на `WindowState.Normal` и поменять значения?

Comment: `WindowState.Maximized` запрещает менять размеры окна, и это логично. Хотите поменять размер окна в коде - установите сначала `WindowState.Normal`, а затем уже меняйте `Height` и `Width`